# Item Removal From Mini Cart error in Magento RWD theme

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

Can anyone help me resolve this error?  If I try to remove an item from the cart by clicking the remove link, I get the following error:

```
#0 /home/paperfun/public_html/practicalproductfundraising.com/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(604): Mage::throwException('Invalid form ke...')
#1 /home/paperfun/public_html/practicalproductfundraising.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->ajaxDeleteAction()
#2 /home/paperfun/public_html/practicalproductfundraising.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('ajaxDelete')
#3 /home/paperfun/public_html/practicalproductfundraising.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /home/paperfun/public_html/practicalproductfundraising.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /home/paperfun/public_html/practicalproductfundraising.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/paperfun/public_html/practicalproductfundraising.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

Comment: now not any issue on cart remove product live site just error exist regarding super menu. and your home page slider wrong way to slider left to right.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this exact error message running Magento CE 1.9.1 with a RWD package. After hours of testing extensions, I found that it was a javascript error.  In my case I had a jquery error from a undefined selector.

I would suggest using Chrome's developer tools to fix any javascript errors that are being displayed.  If you are receiving a javascript error message it is most likely inhibiting your ajaxDeleteAction from functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.9.3.3

Remove all code in skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/slideshow.js and refresh.

Works for me